# Plotly in PowerBI does not export plot after clicking camera icon

Tags: powerbi, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly, powerbi-custom-visuals

I can successfully implement a Plotly visual as an Interactive Power BI Custom Visuals with R (thanks to https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-power-bi-custom-visuals-with-r-a6a4ac998710).

But when I click on the camera icon to export the visual via "download plot as a png", it says "Snapshop succeeded - newplot.png", but I cannot find that file anywhere on my computer.

It works neither in PowerBi Desktop nor Online, but it works without any problems in R Studio. In R studio the png is saved into my download folder by default and I can also specify the folder via config(fig, toImageButtonOptions = "folder/file.png"), cp. https://plotly.com/r/configuration-options/.

But even this does not help when the plotly camera is clicked within PowerBI.

How can I fix this?